# System.getProperty("user.dir") alternative

Tags: java, path, directory

I would like to write JSon files in my Java Application, it works perfectly in my IDE but as soon as I move the directory, the system fails to write the file. I eventually found the problem : The line `System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns a bad path.

The files are located in `C:\wamp\www\myProject` during development. Here is my code at the moment :

```
String url = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\json\\Crc.json";
//Returns "C:\wamp\www\myProject\src\json\Crc.json"
```

After moving my project to `C:\Users\myUser\Desktop` :

```
String url = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\json\\Crc.json";
//Returns "C:\Users\myUser\src\json\Crc.json"
```

I would like to have a way to find where my project directory is on the computer at anytime. Do you guys have a solution ?

Comment: Why not to move the `Crc.json` to your `resources` folder and get access to file via classpath?

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir")` always returns the directory where `java` was run from. It looks to me as if the output is just as expected.

Comment: @jahra Wait, how can I do that ? I currently do not have a resource folder, am I supposed to create it in the `\src` or in the generated `\build` ?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238208/properties-files-in-regular-src-folder-okay may be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `C:\wamp\www\myProject` folder is just a random place on your hard disk.

Java supports 3 generic places to look for resources:

1. the *current working directory*. this is where your command prompt is and what `System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns, but you cannot rely on that beeing somehow related to any cretain place in the file system, especially not related to the project structure on your own system.

   You should only use that if your program has a command line interface and looks for some default file name to work with.
2. the *user home* This is what you get when calling `System.getProperty("user.home")`. On Unix this resoves to `$HOME` and on Windows to `%USERPROFILE%`.

   This is the best place for files changed at runtime or holding user specific content.
3. the *own code location*. Resources in the same package as your class are accessed with `getClass().getResource("filenameWithoutPath")` But usually you place resources in a special folder in the application root and access it like this: `getClass().getResource("/relative/path/from/src/root/filenameWithoutPath")`.

   In your IDE this special folder should be `Project/src/main/resources` (according to the [maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

   This is appropriate for some global configurations that you change when creating the delivery package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Although, there is something I don't quite get : When using the `user.home` property, it always returns `C:\Users\currentUser`, do you mean that I should save the json file in this folder ?

Comment: I also tried the `getClass().getResource("/json/Crc.json")` and the problem I get is when I execute my generated .jar, the path that come out is `\pathOfProject\dist\myProject.jar!\json\Crc.json`, and I'm not sure why it adds the .jar in the path

Comment: *"it always returns C:\Users\currentUser, do you mean that I should save the json file in this folder ?"*, yes, if that is a user specific file.

Comment: *"and I'm not sure why it adds the .jar in the path "* This is because the file is expected to be inside the jar.

Comment: Ok, I'm now saving json files in the user directory and it works fine. But what if I have a folder to store images like `myProject\src\img`, how can I access this one wherever the folder `myProject` is on the computer ? Sorry to bother you with my beginner questions but you've been really helpful...